# Is there a race condition here and how to handle it?

Tags: python, tornado

Does this code have a race condition or do race condition only happen in coroutines?
How would I solve this race condition, preferably without using libraries?

```
class Handler(WebSocketHandler):
    listeners = {}

    def open(self, sub):
        self.subscriptions = [sub]
        Handler.listeners.setdefault(sub, set()).add(self)

    def on_close(self):
        for sub in self.subscriptions:
            Handler.listeners[sub].remove(self)
            if not Handler.listeners[sub]:
                # here in between someone might subscribe
                # so we delete non empty set! which is wrong
                del Handler.listeners[sub]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No race condition; Tornado applications are generally single-threaded. Unless you have yourself explicitly started any threads, then only the main thread is running in your application. Thus, your code cannot be interrupted between checking for `not Handler.listeners[sub]` and executing `del`.

Even if you used coroutines, code like yours would still have no race. A coroutine cannot be interrupted, except when it executes a `yield` statement. It's one of the best features of coroutines. [Consider this long and excellent post by Twisted's author](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/tag/async.html) in which he argues that explicit async programming (with callbacks or `yield` statements) is superior to multithreading, because in async programming race conditions are so much easier to spot.